# WordPress hook for opening a post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am very new to WordPress plugin development.

I have been searching this for a quite a while now but I am currently creating a plugin and I need my plugin to start logging the amount of views a post has had. I already know what I want this part of to do however I am having trouble find out how to a php function for when a post is viewed by a visitor to my WordPress site.

Could someone please show me what the wordpress hook/event is to run a function on post view/load? I want to do this without the use of template as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use post meta for count the post view. when a user view post that is single.php file you can place your custom function on this file. which update post meta when a user view post.

Another way is that you hook you custom function which count and update post meta in the following filter hook

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter' );
```

Comment: Using the 'the_content' how would I still echo the main content like it should be doing?
I dont quite understand the single.php is that a template file or? @Sandeep Kumar

Comment: single.php is the template file which is for detail of any post.